# How to dynamically change the text content of svg in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

My requirement is to remove the text element from `g` and another text element.
But when I run this code, text which written is removed perfectly but adding new text tag is not showing. When I open the developer section of Chrome, it shows my added `text` tag but it is not showing in view. And when I update any thing from developer section of chrome then DOM again reload and my new text would be shown in view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <svg id="t">
    <g>
        <text x="10" y="10">hello</text>
    </g>
    </svg>
    <script>
            var s = document.getElementById('t');
            var g = s.childNodes[1];
            console.log(g.childNodes[1].remove());//remove text must in my case
            var txt = document.createElement('text');
            txt.setAttribute('x', '10');
            txt.setAttribute('y', '10');
            var t = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");
            txt.appendChild(t);
            g.appendChild(txt);

    </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you still have problems with your question? or did one of the answers help you to solve it?

Comment: if one of the answers solved your problem please [accept it like described here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you solved the problem on your own, please post your solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `createElementNS` when creating SVG elements

```
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bc1t6xkm/)

Comment: sir, can u explain me how i use foreignObject in place of text tag that u dyanamically created . In that foriegnObject i have to use text tag. Both foreignObject and text tag are dynamically created.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the text you don't have to remove the entire element and recreate it. You could simply change the textcontent by selecting the text element and set new content to it like following:

```
document.getElementById('t').childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML= "This is a paragraph";
```

See working example here:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <svg id="t">
    <g>
        <text x="10" y="10">hello</text>
    </g>
    </svg>
    <script>
            document.getElementById('t').childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML= "This is a paragraph";//remove text must in my case

    </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working within d3 you can simply do
`d3.select('#svgTextId').html(newHTML)`.